# Representing NodeJS MongoDB Query as String

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I like to store mongodb queries as string. I would like to load and execute them. How can I convert the parameter object used in find to a string without loosing information?

I have already tried to use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse, but it seems, that JSON.parse does not revert JSON.stringify completely.

```
historyCollection.find({"date":{$gte:new Date("2018-12-20 13:47:57.461Z")}, $or:[{"source":2}, {"source":3}]}).limit(4).toArray(function (err2, result2) {
    // Do Stuff
});
```